# Compute mean from list of NumPy array of different sizes

Tags: python, numpy

What is the most efficient way of computing `mean` and `std` of a Python list containing NumPy arrays of different sizes? For example:

```
l = [np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([4,5,6,7]), np.array([8])]
```

Using loop and manually adding it up is a valid solution but I am looking for something more sophisticated.

Comment: I am not sure, what you mean by sophisticated.But personally I prefer to do `l_mean = [i.mean() for i in l] and I_std = [i.std() for i in l]`

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't perfectly clear but I want to compute `mean` and `std` of the whole list and not each NumPy array independently.

Comment: `hstack` can join them into one array.  If you don't like that,  show use how you'd do the loop.

Comment: The full requirements shouldn't come out in bits and dribbles.  If you want the `mean` of the whole list, and the arrays are really 2d, then say so.  The key to gaining `numpy` efficiency is to create a numeric numpy array.  With a list of arrays that can be tricky depending on how the arrays vary in shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [208]: l = [np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([4,5,6,7]), np.array([8])]
```

Making an array from `l` doesn't do much for us, since the arrays differ in shape:

```
In [209]: np.array(l)                                                                                        
Out[209]: array([array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6, 7]), array([8])], dtype=object)
```

`Out[209]` is 1d object dtype.  It can't be `flattened` any further.

`hstack` is useful, turning the list of arrays into one array:

```
In [210]: np.hstack(l)                                                                                       
Out[210]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
In [211]: np.mean(_)                                                                                         
Out[211]: 4.5
```

If the list contains 2d arrays as revealed in a comment:

```
In [212]: ll = [np.ones((2,4)), np.zeros((3,4)), np.ones((1,4))*2]                                           
In [213]: ll                                                                                                 
Out[213]: 
[array([[1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1.]]), array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.]]), array([[2., 2., 2., 2.]])]
In [214]: np.vstack(ll)                                                                                      
Out[214]: 
array([[1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2.]])
In [215]: np.mean(_, axis=0)                                                                                 
Out[215]: array([0.66666667, 0.66666667, 0.66666667, 0.66666667])
```

`np.concatenate(..., axis=0)` would work for both cases.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```
np.mean( map( np.mean, a ) )
```

"Look, ma, no loops!!" =)

Another way would be:

```
np.mean( np.array( a ).flatten() )
```

Comment: Could you please explain this a little bit. My problem is a tad more complex. I have a list of 2D arrays where the first dimension vary and the second one is always 10. I want to compute `mean` and `std` over all 2D arrays, for each index in the second dimension.

Comment: @carobnodrvo `map()` takes the second argument `a` (your list of arrays) and applies the first argument `np.mean()` calculating the average of every array and putting them in the list. another `np.mean()` takes care about calculating the average of the resulting list.

Comment: I see, but the same thing couldn't be applied for `std`, right?

Comment: @carobnodrvo for your complex problem, please, take a look at the documentation of `np.mean()`, because I could be easily mistaken. basically, you have to apply `np.mean( a, axis = 0 )` to get an average over the first dimension. the rest is up to you, one simple loop won't hurt anyone.

Comment: @carobnodrvo and I'm pretty sure `np.std()` takes `axis` argument as well.

Comment: In my book `map` is still a python level loop.  Does `flatten` do anything to a 1d object dtype array?

Comment: @hpaulj if you have a question, you're welcome to stackoverflow -- the web site where questions get asked and answered. just don't do that in comments =)

Comment: That was meant to be an instructive question.  Using the list of of arrays that the OP gives us, does `np.array(a).flatten()` do what you expect?  I'm not a new contributor!

Answer (score 0):

**Method-1**   You can use `itertools`:-

```
import itertools
l = [np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([4,5,6,7]), np.array([8])]
new_l = list(itertools.chain(*l))
print(new_l)
print(f"The mean is:\t{np.mean(new_l)} ")
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
The mean is:    4.5
```

**Method-2**   But I think you should use basic `for` loop:-

```
l = [np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([4,5,6,7]), np.array([8])]
new_l = [var for my_list in l for var in my_list]
np.mean(new_l)
```

Comment: OP asked to avoid loops and you put the double loop in method 2

Comment: @lenik yes, I knew it. That's why it is in method-2(extra method).

Comment: `itertools.chain` flattens a list. But the result is still a list, which np.mean has to convert to an array.